# Stochastic Processes, Doob's Inequality

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

please confirm if the following is correct.

> Let $A = \{V_\tau > \epsilon\}$  and  $\alpha = \min(\alpha_1,\tau)$, where $\alpha_1 = \min\{t\geq 0: X_t\geq \epsilon\}$ (So intuitively, $\alpha$ is a stopping time since it is the minimum of stopping times). Now consider the following inequalities:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> E(A_\tau)\geq E(A_\alpha)\quad &\textrm{(since $A$ is increasing and $\alpha\leq \tau)$} \\ 
>  E(A_\alpha)\geq E(X_\alpha) \quad  &\textrm{(given, since $\alpha$ is a stopping time)}.\end{align}
>  $$
>   So we have
>    $$\begin{align}E(A_\tau)\geq E(A_\alpha)\geq E(X_\alpha)&=\int_{\Omega} X_\alpha \,\mathrm dP=\int_{A} X_\alpha \,\mathrm dP + \int_{A^\prime} X_\alpha \,\mathrm dP\\
> &\geq \int_{A} \epsilon \,\mathrm dP + \int_{A^\prime} X_\alpha \,\mathrm dP \\&\geq \epsilon \Pr(A)\end{align}
> $$
>    and hence the result.

Comment: This needs some heavy rewriting before becoming simply coherent: what is $V$? what is $\tau$? what is $V_\tau$? what is $(X_t)$? how come that later on one needs $A_\tau$ and not $A$? And so on. (And a rather stunning upvote to top it all...)